# Validation of username OR phone number - compare

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, jwt

I am currently just doing a very simple and basic login system with either a email address or a phone number. No password.

Nothing major to hide, just an information hub.

**What i want to achieve:**

- Check if user entered email exists within users array.
- Check if users entered phone exists within users array. Check if both email and phone match the same user.
- Check if email is wrong and phone is drop (or vice versa) - it still finds the right user.

**Whats currently happening:**

- It finds the right user if the email is entered in.
- If email is entered in wrong and phone number is correct, i get a undefined error.
- If both are wrong i get a server error stating email is undefined.

**The code:**

**Users object**

```
const users = [
    {
        email: "jon@doe.com",
        phone: "0798888888",
        name: "John Doe",
        access: ["home", "blah", "etc"]
    },
    {
        email: "fakedoe@john.com",
        phone: "079000000",
        name: "Fake Doe",
        access: ["home", "etc"]
    }
];
```

**Main code:**

```
app.post("/in", async (req, res) => {
    let email = req.body.email,
        phone = req.body.phone;

    let conditions = !!email ? { email } : { phone };
    let data = users.find((x) => x.email === conditions.email || x.phone === conditions.phone);
    let pass = data.email || data.phone !== undefined;

    console.log(pass);

    if (pass) {
        if (conditions.email && conditions.email === data.email) {
            pass = true;
        }

        if (conditions.phone && conditions.phone === data.phone) {
            pass = true;
        }
    }

    if (pass) {
        res.cookie("JWT", jwtSign(req.body.email, data.name, data.access));
        res.status(200);
        res.send("OK");
    } else {
        res.status(200);
        res.send("Invalid user/password");
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe try changing `let pass = data.email || data.phone !== undefined;` to `let pass = data.email !== undefined && data.phone !== undefined;`

Comment: @ZachJensz Now if email is not entered and phone number is correct, it works. If email is entered and phone number is not, it works. If email is wrong and phone number is right, it fails and says email is undefined.

Comment: Change the `&&` to `||`?

Comment: @ZachJensz same result - it fails when email is wrong and phone number is right. But if email is right and phone number is wrong, it works.

Comment: I'm looking through the logic below which changes the variable again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> login system with either a email address or a phone number

Had to find a way to play around with the code. Here is a working version!

```js
const users = [{
    email: "fakedoe@john.com",
    phone: "079000000",
    name: "Fake Doe",
    access: ["home", "etc"]
  }
];
function checkUserExists(email, phone) {
  return !!users.find((x) => x.email === email || x.phone === phone);
}

console.log(checkUserExists('fakedoe@john.com', '0490')); //email
console.log(checkUserExists('fakedoe@joh.com', '079000000')); //phone
console.log(checkUserExists('fakedoe@john.com', '079000000')); //both
console.log(checkUserExists('fakedoe@joh.com', '0490')); //none
```

So replace this:

```js
app.post("/in", async (req, res) => {
    let email = req.body.email,
        phone = req.body.phone;

    let conditions = !!email ? { email } : { phone };
    let data = users.find((x) => x.email === conditions.email || x.phone === conditions.phone);
    let pass = data.email || data.phone !== undefined;

    console.log(pass);

    if (pass) {
        if (conditions.email && conditions.email === data.email) {
            pass = true;
        }

        if (conditions.phone && conditions.phone === data.phone) {
            pass = true;
        }
    }

    if (pass) {
        res.cookie("JWT", jwtSign(req.body.email, data.name, data.access));
        res.status(200);
        res.send("OK");
    } else {
        res.status(200);
        res.send("Invalid user/password");
    }
});
```

with this:

```
function userExists(email, phone) {
  return !!users.find((x) => x.email === email || x.phone === phone);
}
app.post("/in", async (req, res) => {
    if (userExists(req.body.email, req.body.phone)) {
        res.cookie("JWT", jwtSign(req.body.email, data.name, data.access));
        res.status(200);
        res.send("OK");
    } else {
        res.status(200);
        res.send("Invalid user/password");
    }
});
```